# how to convert the 2d image into 3d object file using vtk

Tags: visual-c++, vtk

how to convert the  image into object file like as .obj or .ply . I need some code written in visualization toolkit and c++.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Image data is pixel data and .obj/ .ply or for that matter .stl is 3D geometry data with Point and Cell (for .obj Cell is Triangle) information.

Your question is not clear, but to give you some steps -

1. First, you need to identify how would you convert the pixels into points? vtkImageDataGeometryFilter might be of help here. Although it might not be sufficient as you will also need triangles data.
2. Once you get vtkPolyData from image data, you can write this data to STL or OBJ or PLY format. You can use following VTK classes for that
   vtkSTLWriter, vtkOBJWriter and vtkPLYWriter.

Comment: can you  share me some code to convert the image( .png ) into object (.stl) file so that I display the object file on the display window?

Comment: You can refer standard VTK example -
https://lorensen.github.io/VTKExamples/site/Cxx/ImageData/ImageDataGeometryFilter/

Change you would need is, you need to use vtkPNGReader to read PNG data.
To set PNG reader output to vtkImageDataGeometryFilter use 
imageDataGeometryFilter->SetInputConnection(pngReader->GetOutputPort());

You can get vtkPolyData from imageDataGeometryFilter's output which you can use to write whatever file format you want to write to.